# What tool is used to generate this stack trace for Ruby grape?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

What tool would I use to generate a stack trace like this?

[image]

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it." Where did you see it? Where have you searched?

Comment: Did you generate this picture, or did someone else? If you did, what did you use? If not, where is the picture from if it is publicly available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd help if you provided the source of the picture, but it looks like the graph itself was the result of the gem ruby-prof.

That gem may contain the software for the output format, or it might use a third party gem. I can't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks Andrew that ended up being it.  I can't find the resource where I got the picture at the moment.